# MUI overriding default styles (PaperProps & BackdropProps)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following `AlertDialog` Component :-

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const useAlertDialogStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  dialogContentRoot: {
    padding: "0px",
  },
}));
export function AlertDialog({
  open,
  setOpen,
  onApprove,
  data,
  dialogTitle,
  dialogContent,
  dialogFooter,
}) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const classes = useAlertDialogStyles();
  const handleApproveClick = () => {
    if (onApprove) {
      onApprove(); // Call the passed handleApprove function
    }
    setOpen(false); // Close the dialog
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        PaperProps={{
          style: {
            backgroundColor: "transparent", // Set the dialog background to transparent
            boxShadow: "none", // Optional: removes the default shadow
            width: "621px",
            maxWidth: "700px",
          },
        }}
        BackdropProps={{
          style: {
            backgroundColor: "rgba(17, 7, 22, 0.50)",
            backdropFilter: "blur(35px)",
          },
        }}
      >
        {dialogTitle()}
        <DialogContent classes={{ root: classes.dialogContentRoot }}>
          {dialogContent(setOpen)}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions style={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
          {dialogFooter ? (
            dialogFooter(handleClose)
          ) : (
            <>
              <button
                className="rejectBtnDetailsAccordion"
                onClick={handleClose}
              >
                No
              </button>
              <button
                className="approveBtnDetailsAccordion"
                onClick={handleApproveClick}
              >
                Yes
              </button>
            </>
          )}
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And I am using it as follows in one of my component as follows

```
import React from "react";
import { AlertDialog } from "./AlertDialog";
import { ReactComponent as HourGlassLoader } from "../../../assets/icons/hourGlassLoader.svg";

export const NewPageLoader = ({ showLoader }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <AlertDialog
        open={true}
        dialogTitle={() => {}}
        dialogFooter={() => {}}
        dialogContent={() => {
          return <HourGlassLoader />;
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

My Question is

1. How can I override the styles of the Dialog PaperProps BackdropProps and pass customStyles in general ?
2. I know that I can pass style as a prop but then what if I want to override the styles for
   `DialogContent` `DialogActions`
3. And Since MUI produces some .mui classes on the fly how can I target those when I am re-using the AlertDialog Component

**EDIT** :- I am using MUI Version 4

Comment: You can pass classes to override. See for [DialogContent](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog-content/#DialogContent-prop-classes) and [DialogActions](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog-actions/#DialogActions-prop-classes)

Answer (score 0):

An example to override styles. It sets the background color to red in DialogContent

You can find the required classes for the component on their respective API docs. Eg: [DialogContent](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog-content/#classes)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  DialogActions,
  Button,
  styled,
} from "@mui/material";

const DialogStyled = styled(Dialog)(() => ({
  "& .MuiDialogContent-root": {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  "& .MuiDialogActions-root": {
    backgroundColor: "green",
  },
}));

export default App = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Open</Button>
      <DialogStyled
        sx={{ "& .MuiDialog-paper": { width: "80%", maxHeight: 435 } }}
        maxWidth="xs"
        open={open}
      >
        <DialogTitle>Phone Ringtone</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent dividers>hello</DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button autoFocus onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>Ok</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </DialogStyled>
    </div>
  );
};
```